# Reading Input from 3 textboxes of PrimalForms into PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell file, say ***TestForm.ps1*** and a PrimalForm file, ***UserForm.ps1***, with 3 textboxes; as in the following code:

```
$FormPath = $PSScriptRoot + "\UserForm.ps1"
$Result = & $FormPath
```

I don't know, how to read the text entered in the 3 textboxes of the UserForm.ps1 into my calling TestForm.ps1.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to modify the code PrimalForm generates to return a value from it's GenerateForm function.

```
#Generated Form Function
function GenerateForm {
########################################################################
# Code Generated By: SAPIEN Technologies PrimalForms (Community Edition) v1.0.9.0
# Generated On: 8/8/2011 2:30 PM
# Generated By: Andy Arismendi
########################################################################

# ... bunch of generated code ...

#Show the Form
$your_form.ShowDialog()| Out-Null

$text_box_values = @{}
$text_box_values.a = $text_box_1.Text
$text_box_values.b = $text_box_2.Text
$text_box_values.c = $text_box_3.Text

return $text_box_values

} #End Function
```

This little example will return a hash table with keys a,b and c which store the text box values.

Comment: It seems exactly, what I want. Let me try it.
Thank you very much for your attention and regards.